# iOS accessibility, how to speak marks within text?

Tags: ios, accessibility

There are some marks just like exclamation mark or question mark, and I found iOS escape them by default. How to speak them out?
Example: 'Tom! First name' or '? My last account'.

Comment: So do you want to speak special characters like ! as exclamation mark (!) and ? as question mark (?) etc. ???

Comment: Yes, because these marks have real meaning, not seperator

Answer (score 1):

You can speak these words to add these marks.... just check

```
apostrophe  ‘
open bracket    [
close bracket   ]
open parenthesis    (
close parenthesis   )
open brace  {
close brace }
open angle bracket  <
close angle bracket >
colon   :
comma   ,
dash    -
ellipsis    …
exclamation mark    !
hyphen  –
period / point / dot / full stop    .
question mark   ?
quote   "
end quote   "
begin single quote  '
end single quote    '
semicolon   ;

Typography  Result
ampersand   &
asterisk    *
at sign @
backslash   \
forward slash   /
caret   ^
center dot  ·
large center dot    •
degree sign °
hashtag / pound sign    #
percent sign    %
underscore  _
vertical bar    |
```

Comment: For Siri you can use these dictation commands... no need of code

Comment: Accessibility vs Siri? I don't know your meaning.